# Responsive CSS grid that doesn't rely on box-sizing

Tags: css, grid, border-box

I tried to search for an answer to this both within Google, and on this website.

I have a website that needs to be made responsive. It's relatively intricate, but it's definitely possible with the design we currently have.

My question is this. Is there a responsive grid system, or an example of a fully responsive grid system that does NOT rely on box-sizing: border-box. After looking at Pure & Bootstrap, it seems both rely on that property to make it work.

When thinking about it in practice, it seems to me that a box-sizing:border-box model would be required to allow the use of percentages appropriately.

Why am I unable to use this method? Support of IE7 is absolutely required for this project. I know there are polyfills and htc files that can be used to force support, however, the scale and size of this site makes these options hard to implement. From what I've read, these options should be used in moderation, and a site of this caliber, it just couldn't be used in moderation.

Thanks.

Comment: The way you can go is making an special CSS file for IE7 also is time to realize that IE7 is pretty obsolete and unused http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201212-201312-bar"

Comment: I'm starting to think more and more that IE7 will require it's own CSS file.
As far as IE7 being obsolete, it definitely is, but it still makes my company quite a bit of money every year, which means our marketing team isn't going to be letting go of it anytime soon. We actually saw a rise in sales in IE7 users in 2013 over 2012.

Comment: Use Bootstrap 2.3.2 it works in ie7 and it doesn't rely on box-sizing. It works perfectly well and you can make it mobile first, there is probably someone whose done it already. Plus, you can just use the grid part of it. However, if the site is already created, it might be easier to just use what you have to make it responsive.

Answer (score 0):

In Twitter Bootstrap 3 you can remove the box-sizing in line 293.

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Just remove this and in input declaration :)

Comment: How does this allow for the sizing of the grid to work? How can I get, say, 10px gutters uniformly, while using percentages to to define my grid widths without this box model?

Comment: The grid will absolutely not work without this, there would be a serious math issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the Bootstrap 2.3.x grid only using it mobile first, it kicks in at the 768 min width, you can change this value. To get this to be seen by IE7 and IE8 use Respond.js and make sure you read their docs. Basically you need to locally link (relative path) to the CSS for Respond.js.

This does not rely on box-sizing:border-box.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

    [class*="span"] {
        float: left;
        min-height: 1px;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    .row {
        width: 100%;
        *zoom: 1;
    }
    .row:before,
    .row:after {
        display: table;
        content: "";
        line-height: 0;
    }
    .row:after { clear: both }
    .row [class*="span"] {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 30px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 2.7624309392265194%;
        *margin-left: 2.709239449864817%;
    }
    .row [class*="span"]:first-child { margin-left: 0 }
    [class*="span"].pull-right,
    .row [class*="span"].pull-right { float: right }
    .row .span12 { width: 100% }
    .row .span11 { width: 91.43646408839778% }
    .row .span10 { width: 82.87292817679558% }
    .row .span9 { width: 74.30939226519337% }
    .row .span8 { width: 65.74585635359117% }
    .row .span7 { width: 57.18232044198895% }
    .row .span6 { width: 48.61878453038674% }
    .row .span5 { width: 40.05524861878453% }
    .row .span4 { width: 31.491712707182323% }
    .row .span3 { width: 22.92817679558011% }
    .row .span2 { width: 14.3646408839779% }
    .row .span1 { width: 5.801104972375691% }
    .row .offset12 { margin-left: 105.52486187845304% }
    .row .offset12:first-child { margin-left: 102.76243093922652% }
    .row .offset11 { margin-left: 96.96132596685082% }
    .row .offset11:first-child { margin-left: 94.1988950276243% }
    .row .offset10 { margin-left: 88.39779005524862% }
    .row .offset10:first-child { margin-left: 85.6353591160221% }
    .row .offset9 { margin-left: 79.8342541436464% }
    .row .offset9:first-child { margin-left: 77.07182320441989% }
    .row .offset8 { margin-left: 71.2707182320442% }
    .row .offset8:first-child { margin-left: 68.50828729281768% }
    .row .offset7 { margin-left: 62.70718232044199% }
    .row .offset7:first-child { margin-left: 59.94475138121547% }
    .row .offset6 { margin-left: 54.14364640883978% }
    .row .offset6:first-child { margin-left: 51.38121546961326% }
    .row .offset5 { margin-left: 45.58011049723757% }
    .row .offset5:first-child { margin-left: 42.81767955801105% }
    .row .offset4 { margin-left: 37.01657458563536% }
    .row .offset4:first-child { margin-left: 34.25414364640884% }
    .row .offset3 { margin-left: 28.45303867403315% }
    .row .offset3:first-child { margin-left: 25.69060773480663% }
    .row .offset2 { margin-left: 19.88950276243094% }
    .row .offset2:first-child { margin-left: 17.12707182320442% }
    .row .offset1 { margin-left: 11.32596685082873% }
    .row .offset1:first-child { margin-left: 8.56353591160221% }

}/* end min-width */
```